# Is there no way to avoid accidentally interacting with windows that jump into focus?

Tags: windows, gui, input

Ever since PC's had graphical interfaces, the same issue reoccurs:

A user is typing on their keyboard or clicking on things. Then, suddenly, the OS decides it's a great time to bring a window from the background into the foreground, or perhaps popup a brand new window. Either way, your typing or clicking now has focus on the new foreground window before your brain even has a chance to process what has happened.

- If the window is a dialog with buttons (OK, Cancel, Yes, No, etc), your typing/clicking may dismiss
  important information, or worse: You end up cancelling a 10-hour file backup process, or force a system restart in the middle of work.
- If the window has text input as the focus, you're now typing in it.
  Perhaps you were typing an email and some of your text is now in the
  popup window. When you pressed Enter for a line return, you ended
  up submitting the popup. Or worse: You entered your password as plain
  text and submitted the popup, or the password is now visible for someone over your shoulder to 
  see (let's hope you weren't sharing your screen for a presentation).

Is there really no way to prevent scenarios like these? (I'll keep this question about Windows OS but I know they all have this issue.) I find it hard to believe that after all these years, there's still no guardrail to protect users from the same reoccurring hazard.

It seems to me that it would be simple to implement something to at least partially mitigate this issue.
Example: Once a new window (especially one not manually called for) pops up and takes focus, it should have a delay (maybe 1 second at least) before input can be accepted. I think I've seen this before (Was it a Windows UAC prompt?) but not nearly often enough.

As I type up this very question, I'm trying to transfer files and every time there's a bad file, a new window pops up with no warning and I keep cancelling the process by accident because I'm typing.

Comment: This is not normal. What are these windows that grab the focus?

Comment: @harrymc I would say it's common enough to be annoyed. Like I said in my question: Windows may ask you want to do with a file transfer issue. It may also ask you if you want to reboot after software is automatically updated. A window may pop up asking what you want to do with a device that was detected (your phone perhaps). The possibilities are endless!

Comment: @harrymc - I just thought of another example: Bluetooth file transfers. If my PC is receiving multiple files via bluetooth, it will bring the bluetooth transfer window in to focus after every single transfer, successful or not.

Comment: The solutions are very limited, as in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand that there is no way in which Windows can totally block applications from stealing the focus and remain functional.
For example, if during a file-copy your anti-virus detected a possible threat
and would like to pop-up a window asking you for the action to take, if this window
is blocked then you would never understand why the copy never terminates.

Nevertheless, the problem can perhaps be mitigated by the following.

**Enable focus-follows-mouse**

This will put the focus into the window that is under the cursor,
so perhaps will avoid your window losing the focus.

In *Control Panel > Ease of Access Center*, click "Make the mouse easier to use",
check the option "Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse"
and click OK.

**Change the timeout for windows getting focus after hovering**

Thios timeout is apecified in the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`,
item `ActiveWndTrkTimeout`, containing the time in milliseconds (ms).
The default value of `0` means the window will get the focus instantly,
which is perhaps what you want.
Log out/in is required after a change.

Answer (score 0):

> Ever since PC's had graphical interfaces, the same issue reoccurs:

That has been since 1990.

1. Pay attention when entering / typing so at (a) you make fewer errors and (b) are ready for the pop-up to continue to the next step.
2. " force a system restart in the middle of work."   Set hours of operation so this does not happen. My systems never restart in the middle of work.
3. "Perhaps you were typing an email and some of your text is now in the popup window."  This truly requires paying attention.
4. "Is there really no way to prevent scenarios like these?"  Not in any way permanently.  After all, it have been refined over and over again for the last 30 years. It does reflect what users have asked for.

Comment: Keep in mind that the popups are not always expected or foreseeable in any capacity. In response to your numbering: 1) The average human reaction time is 0.25 seconds. Most people type faster than 4 keys per second. 2) I'm not sure what you're implying. Consider when SW updates itself in the background and suddenly asks you to reboot now or later. 3) See my response to item 1.

Comment: When writing your answer, did you wait after each keystroke to check for popups? I argue it's impossible to do so while remaining any what efficient as far as time is concerned.

Comment: If I am typing text (Word), pop-ups do not normally occur. That largely takes care of reaction time. When clicking or entering like that, I move patiently expecting that the system may feed back to me. I do this from habit formed out of many years of use. Everyone will get trapped some time or other (that is why so many auto collisions). We need to be alert.  And remember that most apps have undo keys to correct errors

Comment: I'm utterly convinced there's a way. An OS could certainly have a policy to not deliver certain keyboard/mouse input events for a short duration (i.e. visual reaction time if not greater, since there is cognitive time to even have a *reason* to interact with the window) other than angrily closing it! It could also be a setting/policy as far as ability to even open unprompted (or after some delay during which other interactions occurred), vs having to request/notify for attention. So much could be done.